# Exception when using @Query to search for a UUID derived from an abstract class

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, eclipselink, jpql

I have an abstract class with:

```
@Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false, length = 36)
    private String uuid;

    public UUID getUuid() {
            if (uuid == null) {
                return null;
            }
        return UUID.fromString(uuid);
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid.toString();
    }
```

and then an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "creatinine")
public class Creatinine extends AbstractEntity {
```

and repository

```
public interface CreatinineRepository extends JpaRepository<Creatinine, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT m FROM Creatinine m WHERE m.uuid = :uuid")
    public Creatinine find(String uuid);
}
```

However the application is throwing an "you have attempted to set a parameter that does not exist in this query string" exception.

I have passed the uuid in the query both as a String and a UUID with the same exception in both cases.  Is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when using named parameters need to add `@Param`

```
public interface CreatinineRepository extends JpaRepository<Creatinine, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT m FROM Creatinine m WHERE m.uuid = :uuid")
    public Creatinine find(@Param("uuid") String uuid);
}
```

If you are using `Java 8` or better be sure to compile with -parameters to avoid @Param annotation for named parameters.

Comment: Of course - lets put it down to brain fade!  Thank you.